# FFmpeg Need More Video Effect Filters

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, effects

I have been trying to find more filters to use with `FFmpeg` but I have only found 2 so far since I cannot use `frei0r` because I am using [Bravobit FFmpeg](https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android).

The two I have found are :

**Sepia**

```
colorchannelmixer=.393:.769:.189:0:.349:.686:.168:0:.272:.534:.131
```

**Black and White**

```
hue=s=0
```

Is there any more of them?

For the ones who can use `frei0r` here is a good link to find more filters : [FFmpeg frei0r filters](https://yalantis.com/blog/experiments-with-ffmpeg-filters-and-frei0r-plugin-effects/)

Comment: You can use 4-5 seconds video or gif images for effects and merge them with your video or image

Comment: @VivekMishra wait, how would I do that, and my videos can be up to 5min long

Comment: Video length doesn't matter. You can loop your effect till the length of your video

Comment: You've probably already seen this, but it's worth mentioning that the [FFmpeg Filter Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) is essentially a descriptive list of all filters.

Comment: Orange: 1:0:0:0:0:.5:0:0:0:0:0